# MySQL sorting date then by part number

Tags: php, mysql, sequence

Essentially I want these parts (below) grouped then the groups place in order of time, starting from the latest time being at the top of the list.

```
ID  Parts       Time
1   SMH_2010    08:59:18    
2   JJK_0101    08:59:26
3   FTD_0002    08:59:24    
4   JJK_0102    08:59:27    
5   FTD_0001    08:59:22    
6   SMH_2010    08:59:20    
7   FTD_0003    08:59:25
```

So, the results would look like:

```
ID    Parts     Time
1   JJK_0101    08:59:26    
2   JJK_0102    08:59:27

3   FTD_0001    08:59:22    
4   FTD_0002    08:59:24    
5   FTD_0003    08:59:25

6   SMH_2010    08:59:20
7   SMH_2010    08:59:18
```

Please, I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: share your query code, you have tried.

Comment: I cannot see the contradiction

Comment: What I mean by contradiction is, I'm telling sql to sort by Time then saying no, now sort by Parts. "So what's is it to be" time or parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. Not my ideal solution but, never the less it works.

I added another field called `max_date` which by default is ‘now()’ as every new part is inserted.

I create a prefix from the current part being inserted, something like “SMH_” as a variable called $prefix = “SMH_”;

I have another query that directly follows the insert, which updates the `max_date` again, by ‘now()’ where the prefix is like `$prefix`.

UPDATE `parts` SET `max_date` = now() WHERE prefix LIKE '%$prefix%'

To display the results I use something along the line of :

SELECT * FROM `parts` ORDER BY parts.max_date DESC, parts.part ASC

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not sorting in the traditional meaning. Your first attempt orders the result by time, and then by part if multiple timestamps occur at the same time.

What you want neither sorts the result in alphabetically by Parts name, nor ascending/descending on timestamp. What you are asking for can't be accomplished by the sort operation in SQL. Having the parts in sequence is not ordering.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this sort of query can't be achieved with mysql. The must be some method to put these in the sequence I need??!

Comment: What needs to happen is, Parts needs to be sorted in order then I need to extrapolate the latest time from each part group (so JJJK_0102 would be    08:59:27). Then it needs sorting by Time. This would then achieve my goal, but HOW??